# Using Entrez.efetch() to retrive .fasta file from any NCBI database?

Tags: fasta, python, phylogenetics, entrez, efetch

I tried to use these python codes to retrieve a .fasta file from gene database, but the output were the parameters of the report

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "send_helps@earth.com"
handle = Entrez.efetch(db = "gene",id = "682",rettype="fasta", retmode="xml")
print(Entrez.read(handle))
```

i also read the documentation on [this site](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.EFetch) about efetch() and seems like this function can only retrieve certain kinds of data for each database. So i can't take fasta file from gene database !?

I don't want to use the NCBI web UI. What's wrong with my code? Is there a way i can guarantee to retreive a .fasta file through python from NCBI ? Am i misundertanding something severly ?

Sorry for bad English. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to download the FASTA sequence of transcript variants using Entrez eutilities, you will have to use `Entrez.elink` to get a list of transcript accessions for the gene of interest and then use `Entrez.efetch` to fetch the sequence(s). Just to give you an idea, you can use [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) for this as follows:

```
elink -db gene -id 682 -target nuccore -name gene_nuccore_refseqrna \
  | efetch -format fasta
```

You can find more Entrez Link descriptions [here](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query/static/entrezlinks.html). Note, there is a `gene_fasta` option for `efetch` but it still returns only the transcript sequence (i.e., no intron sequence).

If you need the full gene sequence (including the intronic regions), you can use the commands mentioned [here](https://github.com/NCBI-Hackathons/EDirectCookbook/issues/47).

Alternatively, you can use [NCBI Datasets](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets) for this. You can use the web interface, command line tool or the python API. [This page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/new/docs/how-tos/genes/) with the how-to articles has the information you seek.