# CLI access to genomes/proteomes by BioSample ID

Tags: python, phylogenetics, identifiers

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9536359/#9536376)*

I'd like to download multiple genome assemblies or proteomes using a set of BioSample IDs from NCBI.

I'm able to find the assemblies belonging to the BioSample IDS in a browser (in the search field of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), but couldn't find a commandline interface solution (CLI).

E.g. for BioSample `SAMN09405588` the assembly id is `PDT000806148.1`, and from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly/GCA_014136285.1/ I can download the proteome: `GCA_014136285.1_PDT000806148.1_protein.faa.gz`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think this question is not a duplicate of https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15794/using-entrez-efetch-to-retrive-fasta-file-from-any-ncbi-database - there a gene id is given, here a biosample id.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from @m, converted from [comment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):*

Biostars are recommending esearch ... its not the approach I'd have taken but presume will do the job. Its available via SRA, so I'd have gone for the SRA toolkit. Is SRA more appropriate in context? (I liked Biostars BeautifulSoup solution)

*[Please update or improve this answer if you can]*